# How about using FLEX 3 component inside Flash file?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Is it possible to use Flex 3  component/code inside Flash (cs4)  SWF file ?

I know its possible in the opposite direction.

Comment: Anybody knows if it can be done with Flex 4???

Comment: I do this regularly - Create a As3 library project, goto properties-compiler settings (FB4) ,  browse to flashbuilde 4\..sdks\libs - pick the flex.swc. use namespace mx_internal; I use the mx.collections.ArrayCollection quite a bit so its useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my minimal testing **it seems you can't use Flex components when building a "pure AS3" project.** (Can we start calling it PAS3 or something? Like "passé". Or "pastry". :)

I did this admittedly limited testing by creating a test project with one AS class as the "document class", which would instantiate and addChild one mx.controls.Button. I copied the whole mx package from the path mentioned by [hasseg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111/hasseg) into the project source path.

This is what I found out:

1. By removing the use of mx_internal from a certain Version.as file, I got Flash IDE to compile my test project without warning. Nothing showed up on the stage though.
2. Using Flex Builder (and the flex compiler, obviously) I also managed to compile the project without errors. I put breakpoints in the code and watched it build itself in the debugger. The components were instantiated flawlessly, but still nothing showed up on the stage. This swf also crashed the browser numerous times.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Flex code in a "pure AS3" project myself, but I don't see why you couldn't do that.

You can download the [Flex SDK](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/flexdownloads/) and get the Flex components from there, both as an `swc` file (under `/frameworks/libs`) and as AS3 source code (under `/frameworks/projects/framework/src`).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this can be done after all: http://labs.wichers.nu/2007/12/25/using-flex-compiled-code-within-flash/

Comment: That link is broken, but i found this several posts that can be helpful: 
http://joshblog.net/2008/02/12/yahoo-actionscript-3-maps-api-in-flash-cs3/ <-- Very good in deed

http://www.deitte.com/archives/2008/08/using_flex_swcs.htm

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/archive/index.php3/t-194113.html

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to use MXML to initialise the Flex framework and use Flex components.

Mike Chambers from Adobe says:

> There is not support for using the Flex Framework in an AS only project. While it is theoretically possible, you would have to manually bootstrap a lot of the application initialization code that Flex handles (something which would be rather complex). - [Source](http://www.mail-archive.com/flashcoders@chattyfig.figleaf.com/msg17761.html)

To see how complex, you can tell the compiler to keep the intermediate AS3 files that it generates from the MXML. Open your AS3 project properties and set `-keep-generated-actionscript` as an argument to the compiler. Compile your project then look in the obj/generated folder. Using Flex 4, I get 13 small files the main of which extends `spark.components.Application` and overrides a few methods.

So it's possible but you probably wouldn't want to do it. Flex is meant to make your life easier, not harder.